# Pass model properties separately to the view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some trouble passing my model to the corresponding view. I'm trying to have only one view for creating and editing my model. I'm also using validation.

I can't seem to figure out an elegant way of passing all model properties to my view as separate variables.

Here's my view:

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}">
</div>
```

I need to pass a variable named `title` to it. But if I were to specify each and every property myself it would become ridiculous.

```
$product = Product::find($id);

return view('admin.products.new',
    ['id' => $id, 'title' => $product['title']]
); // this is stupid
```

I could pass the model as a whole to the view but then I would have to change the view to check if the variable is set and then get the nested child value out of it. This would break validation.

```
$product = Product::find($id);

return view('admin.products.new',
    ['product' => $product]
); // this is stupid
```

and in the view:

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="{{ $product['title'] ?? '' }}">
</div>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Since `$product` is an array, why not just pass the `$product` array directly to the view? `view('admin.products.new', $product)`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That's possible but maybe I need to pass more variables that are not directly related to the product. What then? I could add them to the product model but that's hardly elegant.

Comment: Well, the "elegant" solution would be to pass the product as `$product` to the view, which you said you don't want.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson How to deal with validation if I pass product?

Comment: How you pass the data to the view shouldn't matter for your validation?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Laravel validation takes the `name` attribute of the form elements and passes it back to the view in case of an error. If the name for a form input is for example `title` then this would be the name of the returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that i think you're looking for

```
/** @var Product $product */
$product = Product::find($id);

foreach($product->getAttributes() as $attribute=>$value)
   View::share($attribute,$value??"");

return view('admin.products.new');
```

Comment: Best way apparently. I make a utility function and put the loop into that and now I can do the whole thing with only one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a trait named ProductTrait.
Also specify the column you want to retrieve. For this example, i'm using id and job title.

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $array = Product::all()->pluck('job_title', 'id')->toArray();
    return $array;
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
$product_info = $this->getProducts();
return view('admin.products.new')->with('product_info',$product_info);
```

Note: don't forget to include "**use App\Traits\ProductTrait;**" in header and also
"**use ProductTrait;**" inside your controller

Output:
[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmeCb.png)

Comment: Way too complicated.